# Comparing Values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [100, 100, 200, 200, 300],
    'B': [123, 456, 789, 789, 101],
    'C': [999, 998, 997, 997, 997] })

print(df)

          A        B         C
0       100      123       999
1       100      456       998
2       200      789       997
3       200      789       997
4       300      101       997
```

I need to find all instances where the values in Col A *have different values* in Col B. So, given the example, the results should return only:

```
          A        B         C
0       100      123       999
1       100      456       998
```

I've tried simple solutions such as groupby.count() but that counts all values.

Comment: I don't understand your criteria. Why is row 4 not part of the solution?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact criteria you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique') > 1]
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  100  123  999
1  100  456  998
```

**Details:**

Use `transform` with `groupby` and `nunique` to return the number of unique values of 'B' in grouping 'A'.  Then, use boolean indexing on the dataframe where the number is greater than 1.